# Kusto legend sorting

Tags: azure, kql

I have a piechart visualization that I'm creating through Azure workspaces. What I'm struggling with is the sorting of the legend itself. In the picture below, I'd like the legend itself to be sorted by the OSVersion value and not the count.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-chart-visualizations#pie-charts), there is no option provided for legend sorting on Azure workspaces. By default legends will always sort by *count* in descending order.
You can have look on [chart-settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-chart-visualizations#chart-settings) options.

I tried to generate chart using sample data and got to know that it is an expected behavior.

**Query**

```
AzureDiagnostics
| summarize  count() by OperationName
| sort  by OperationName
```

**Result**

[image]

**Chart Settings configuration**

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation thus the ask. Thanks for the info